# Trying to add additional traces to an existing Matplotlib figure

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using a function which spits out a figure object of validation data. My script calculates a few model parameters that I would like to plot on top of this existing figure object. How can I do this? Whenever I try to plot my modeled data, it does so in a new window. Here's what my code looks like:

```
datafig = plotting_function(args) #Returning a figure object

datafig.show()

plt.plot([modeled_x],[modeled_y]) #Plotting in a new window
```

I've tried using plt.hold() / plt.hold(True) but this doesn't do anything. Any ideas?

Edit:

MCVE:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def fig_create():

    fig_1, ax_1 = plt.subplots()
    ax_1.plot([0,1],[0,1])

    fig_2, ax_2 = plt.subplots()
    ax_2.plot([0,1],[0,5])

    return fig_1, ax_1, fig_2, ax_2

figure_1, axes_1, figure_2, axes_2 = fig_create()
plt.close("all") # Spyder plots even without a plt.show(), so running the function generates figures. I'm closing them here.

figure_2.show()
plt.figure(2)
plt.plot([0,1],[0,10])
```

Result of the MCVE: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UtzGq.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify which axis to plot on. `plt.figure(2)` will  make a figure with a number of 2, regardless of whether an existing figure has that number or not!  `axes_2.plot()`, however will plot whatever data you input directly onto `axes_2` and whatever was there already. If it doesn't immediately show up you should add `plt.draw()` after the plot function.

Try not to mix plt, notation and ax notation as this will create confusion later on! If you are using fig and ax, stick with those!

Answer (score 0):

You can specify which figure to plot to by calling `plt.figure(my_figure_index)` before any `plt.plot` (or any other `plt` plotting function) call.

For example:

```
plt.figure(10) # creates new figure if doesn't exist yet
plt.plot(...) # plots in figure 10

plt.figure(2) # creates new figure if doesn't exist yet
plt.plot(...) # plots in this figure 2

plt.figure(10) # figure already exists, just makes it the active one
plt.plot(...) # plots in figure 10 (in addition to already existing stuff)
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I've given your suggestion a shot already and Python just makes another figure with the same #. No error or anything:

https://i.imgur.com/5clWmRM.png

For reference, I'm using Spyder. Note that when I plot "datafig", or the figure object that already exists, it defaults to Figure 2.

Comment: Nope, just one!

Comment: Don't understand why you use `plt.close("all")`. It makes the code crash for me (`figure_2` is `None`). And works perfectly fine without it...

Comment: Odd, perhaps this problem is specific to Spyder. If my example above does not reproduce the issue for you then it sounds like it's on my end. Thanks for your help regardless!